# Sequence of continuous functions convergent to continuous by each variable function in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, continuity

Solving a problem from a book, in the hints section I encountered a statement, which I cannot prove. Let $\bar{U}$ be a closed circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $f:\bar{U}\to\mathbb{R}$ a function, continuous with respect to each of the two variables (as a one-variable function). Prove, that there exists a sequence of continuous functions $\{f_n:\bar{U}\to\mathbb{R},n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, such that $f_n$ converges to $f$ pointwise, i.e. $\forall(x_0,y_0)\in\bar{U}, \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f_n(x_0,y_0)=f(x_0,y_0)$. Please, help me to prove this statement.

Comment: I may be wrong, but what is wrong with taking $f_n=f$?

Comment: $f$ is not necessarily continuous in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with respect to the metric $||x-y||=\sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2+(x_2-y_2)^2}$ (for $x=(x_1,y_1), y=(x_2,y_2)$), it is only continuous with respect to one variable (i.e. with each fixed $x$ $f(x,y)$ is continuous with respect to y and with each fixed $y$ $f(x,y)$ is continuous with respect to $x$), while $f_n$ must be continuous with respect to both variables, i. e. with respect to the mentioned metric.

Comment: Oh now I see it, never mind sorry